# Purchases in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some features of an iOS App to be available after the user chooses to upgrade the app or by simple paying some bucks. Those features will be some sections/modules available if payment received.

1. What will be the best and most efficient way to implement it? In-App purchase or a Third Party Payment Gateway like PayPal, Stripe etc. ?
2. Please suggest and explain pros and cons of both in brief.

Comment: vote to close : primarily opinion based... I believe this is what you need to finalize. All are efficient way...

Comment: In-App Purchase : Never. Apple already deduct 30% also you will receive amount once a year...  Go with your country online payment system. You will have money instantly in your account...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Can you clarify me on this regarding the requirement of app I have mentioned?

Comment: If you want to use something other than Apple's in-app purchase system you will need to process the payment on a separate web site and you cannot link to the web site from your app

Comment: You are going to have a very difficult time getting this past the apple review process. The app review guidelines specifically say that third party in app payments are forbidden